# How do genes get passed from one hive to another?

Tags: genetics

In hive species, like honeybees, how do genes propagate from one hive to another?

If the queen only mates with drones from the same hive, and queens and drones are born to the hive they end up mating in, I'd expect that each hive would end up like its own little species, a tiny gene pool with no outside influence.  But since honeybees haven't broken into myriad local species, there must be some gap in my understanding here.

Comment: See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuptial_flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuptial_flight)